# Log in to Windows 10 as Administrator using RDP

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, administrator, uac

I have two Windows 10 machines.  I remote into the desktop using my laptop.  Remote works, but I cannot get Administrator access.  Both are Windows 10 Pro.  Both have the same local accounts, each with Administrator.  If I log in directly, both give me Administrator access.  Before I upgraded from Windows 8.1, I was able to remote as Administrator, at least as I recall.  However, when I remote to the desktop, I do not have Administrator on that desktop.

I've tried about everything I know, including running RDP itself As Administrator.  UAC is on Always Notify on both machines.

Is it possible to RDP as Administrator on Windows 10?  If so, how?  Thanks...

EDIT: Symptoms, in particular:  Settings screen is blank, save for a gear in the center.  Attempting to uninstall programs, the response was that I needed to be an administrator.  UAC does allow me to elevate privileges, however.

Comment: Something you could try would be to create a new account on the system and put that account in the Administrators and Remote Desktop Users groups, or add an existing account to those groups, and see whether the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand this answer, but I am going to provide it in case it helps anyone else.  Understand, I have had this problem for weeks, but it was just an annoying hindrance so I didn't really dig in until now.

I finally logged in remotely as the real "Administrator" to see if that worked.  It had already worked locally but, given my experience, I was surprised when it did work.  After about a 30 second wait, the Settings panel displayed normally.  Then things got weird.

I went back to my original local account that was assigned group Administrators but was not working.  Again, after about 30 seconds or so, it worked and the Settings panel displayed normally.  Earlier today and in the past weeks, I have let that panel sit for very long periods without change.  Only after I logged in as "Administrator" did it work.

Answer (score 1):

Do you receive the error message "The connection was denied because the user account is not authorized for remote login" or do you see another error message? You can verify the account is granted remote login capability through the following steps:

1. Right-click on the Windows Start button.
2. Select **Control Panel**.
3. Click on **System and Security**.
4. Click on **Administrative Tools**.
5. Double-click on **Computer Management**.
6. Under **Local Users and Group**, double-click on **Remote Desktop Users** in the right pane of the window.
7. Is the administrator account or "administrators" in the **Remote Desktop Users** group? If not click on the **Add** button to add the account or accounts to which you wish to grant remote login access.

Alternatively, you can click on **Users** under **Local Users and Groups** then double-click on the relevant account, then click on the **Member Of** tab. If you don't see **Remote Desktop Users** listed as one of the groups to which the account belongs, click on the **Add** button and then add **Remote Desktop Users** as a group to which the account belongs.

[Example for a domain administrator account](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/domain/RemoteLogon/), but the process for checking remote login access for a local administrator account is the same.

Comment: As I indicated, the session works fine with the exception that I am not an administrator.  I cannot change settings, as it gives me a blank screen with a settings gear in the center, in particular.

Comment: This works if I am logged in locally.  And, I can use User Accounts to Manage Other Accounts either way, however...  And, yes, I am a member of Administrators on both systems.

Comment: When you stated "Remote works, but I cannot get Administrator access," I thought you meant that you could establish a connection to the system via RDP, but couldn't log in under the administrator account. If you issue the command `whoami /groups` from a [command prompt](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/win8/cmd_prompt.php) while logged in via RDP, do you see "BUILTIN\Administrators" listed? Is there something in particular you are trying to do that doesn't work when you log in remotely, but does when you login locally?

Comment: Yes, it shows I am a member of BUILTIN\Administrators both locally and remotely.  I updated the original question to elaborate on the symptoms.

Comment: I'm normally logging into Windows systems remotely as a domain administrator, but I just tried logging into a Windows 10 system via RDP under a local administrator account on the system to confirm that access should be the same. I uninstalled a program I needed to upgrade anyway. I was able to uninstall the program without any prompt to provide administrator credentials and accessing "Settings" showed a normal display, so, though I can't, unfortunately, say why you are experiencing those problems, I can say you should not be seeing those symptoms.

Comment: Good information.